# Is it possible to use a playstation save on a pc version?

Tags: pc, final-fantasy-7, emulation, ps1

I almost finished Final Fantasy VII on a PSX emulator running on Ubuntu, but now I would like to play the last hours on the pc version, maybe with graphical and audio mods (non-MIDI music and characters in the map as during the fights).

Is that possible?

Comment: do you need any further help with this question, or are you satisfied with @Macha's answer?

Comment: @andy: it would be great if you can help! Please, answer as usual. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

No, it isn't. The PSX emulator's save is one of two things:

- A savestate - a dump of the emulated PS1's RAM.
- A virtual memory card - A file representing a PS1 memory card.

Understandably, neither of these are readable by a PC game.

On top of that, even if it was possible to extract the game's save from a virtual memory card, there is absolutely no guarantee that the format for the PC version is the same. It's more likely that it was changed during the port.